# Integration of node-whatsapi in meteor

Tags: meteor, npm, whatsapi

I want to be able to nose whatsapi in meteor. I am using

- latest stable meteor
- node-whatsapi
- arunoda´s meteorhacks:npm

and can get the past the basics:

On meteor server startup, I have:

```
whatsapi = Meteor.npmRequire('whatsapi');
wa = whatsapi.createAdapter({
    msisdn: '....',
    username: '....',
    password: '....',
    ccode: '....'
});

wa.connect(function connected(err) {
    if (err) {console.log(err); return;}
    console.log('Connected');
    wa.login(logged);
});

function logged(err) {
    if (err) {console.log(err); return;}
    console.log('Logged in');
    wa.sendIsOnline();
};
```

... which let me send and receive messages with a method call to

```
wa.sendMessage(recipient, content, function(err, id) {
    if (err) {console.log(err.message); return;}
    console.log('Server received message %s', id);
});
```

The code bellow also works, logging received messages on the console. This sits inside server Meteor.startup:

```
wa.on('receivedMessage', function(message) {
    console.log("From: " + message.from);
    console.log(message.body);
});
```

My problem is that when I try to add store message.from or message.body into a collection, meteor gives me "Meteor code must always run within a Fiber" error")

```
wa.on('receivedMessage', function(message) {
    console.log("From: " + message.from);
    console.log(message.body);
    Recipients.insert({msgfrom: message.from});
});
```

Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Meteor.bindEnvironment](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/timers) to wrap any callback given out by your npm module. It will wrap the callback into a 'Fiber' so you can run Meteor code in it.

For example:

```
wa.on('receivedMessage', Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(message) {
    console.log("From: " + message.from);
    console.log(message.body);
    Recipients.insert({msgfrom: message.from});
}));
```

What it does essentially is place the code in the callback into a Fiber.